# Validation plugin files are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am doing my form validation with jquery validation plugin. Everything seems fine but its not working. No message appears. Or may be its due to files that I have included.
files included

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.6/jQuery.Validate.min.js"></script>
```

here is jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function($){
        $("#joinform").validate({
                rules: {
                firstname: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 30
                },
                lastname: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 30
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                },
                repassword: { 
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                }
            },
            messages: {
                firstname: { 
                    required: "Please enter your firstname",
                    maxlength: "Firstname is too large" 
                },
                lastname: { 
                    required: "Please enter your lastname",
                    maxlength: "Lastname is too large" 
                },
                email: { 
                    required: "Please enter email address",
                    email: "Please enter the valid email" 
                },
                password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long"
                },
                repassword: {
                    required: "Please confirm your password",
                    equalTo:"Passwords should be same"
               }        
            }


        });
    });

</script>
```

here is html.

```
<form role="form" name="joinform" id="joinform" action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name: </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required/>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname"   placeholder="Last Name" required/>
        <br/>

          <label for="email">Email: </label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" required email/>
        <br/>

          <label for="pwd">Password: </label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="at least 6 characters long" required/>


          <label for="repass">Retype-Password:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="repassword" placeholder="Confirm your password" required/>
      <br/>

          <a href="login.php" style="color:#666666; text-decoration:underline; ">Already a member?Login</a><br/>

   <br/>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
   </div>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using any jQuery plugin, you ***must*** load jQuery first. You are also including the plugin twice.  You ***must not*** include each plugin more than once... preferably use the latest version.

This is correct...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, use the latest plugin version supported by your version of jQuery...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanku so much. it worked!! I was stuck for many days. Its was due to duplicate files i was adding thanku :)